# How to delete user's logo if user has been deleted in Laravel 4?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

**DESCRIPTION**

I have a field in my database called: **logo_path** in my **users** table.
logo_path will only store a **path** to a logo.
I also have a logo_path folder in my **app/files/logo_path/**

I have a create user form, when creating a user, I allow a user to upload their desire avatar/logo.

**WORK**

The process of creating an account is work, the upload is also work, the file is also save to where I wanted.

**PROBLEM**

Here comes one small problem, I have a lot of randoms photo in my logo_path folder now.
All of them is getting annoying, I was wondering if there is there a way to delete it's logo of that user if the user has been deleted ?

**UserController --> destroy()**

```
public function destroy($id){

    $user = User::find($id);
    $user->delete();

    return Redirect::to('/users/');

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add

`$success = File::delete(base_path().'/app/files/logo_path/'.$user->logo_path);`

**UPDATED** : UserController

```
public function destroy($id){

    $user = User::find($id);
    $user->delete();
    $success = File::delete(base_path().'/app/files/logo_path/'.$user->logo_path);

    return Redirect::to('/users/');

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Often, something like this can happen in more than one place. Rather than catching them all in the controller, Laravel's model events can let you do this in one place reliably.

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#model-events

```
class User extends Eloquent {
    public static function boot() {
        parent::boot();

        User::deleted(function($user) {
            // now that the user has been deleted, delete their logo
            File::delete('path/to/logos/' . $user->logo);
        }
    }

}
```